# Dad (mid 50s) wants me to help him invest ~500k?

Tags: investing, real-estate, stock-markets, certificate-of-deposit

My dad is in his mid 50s right now, and he has ~500,000 in his savings account. He has approximately 1 million in his 401k. He feels bad that he missed out on the rally of the past 9 years and wants my help to invest the 500k he currently has in cash.

I'm a bit hesitant to tell him to throw it all in equity-based index funds (mainly because he's coming very close to retirement) so I'm a bit confused as to what advice to give him.

Also, judging by the fact that he hasn't invested this money already, he's probably on the more risk-averse side of the scale.

I've been thinking about recommending that he look into real estate and maybe get a condo to rent out? I don't have too much experience with that though, so I'd appreciate any pointers on the pros/cons with that strategy. Also thinking about recommending CDs. What do you guys think about other investments? Munis? Corp Bonds?

Would appreciate any other ideas/investments that would suite his risk profile. Thanks!

Comment: What was the $1million in? Did he "miss out" in his 401k too or does he just wish that ALL of his money had been in equities?

Comment: Also, what training or expertise do you have to help your dad invest? Why not just hire an investment advisor? I personally wouldn't want to be responsible for a half million dollar investment account without some expertise.

Comment: The amount of money  involved is too large  for someone with little experience to advise.  Have your father get some professional help.

Comment: Will you be the one to blame if your dad isn't happy with the investment?

Comment: I disagree with those suggesting you hire someone. Financial advisors charge a lot of money and often don't add that much value. A basic diversified portfolio is not hard to come up with and implement. I only suggest financial advisors for people who are mentally declining and unable to handle their affairs and don't have children who can make a few basic trades for them.

Comment: Get a condo? Seems to me like pretty high risk and high maintenance investment, especially if you are not an expert in the real estate field!

Comment: @farnsy there's a lot more to it than that. You need to consider risk appetite and tolerance, investment horizon, financial goals, etc. There are advisors that will help you choose broad investments for relatively small fees, and those that will pick individual stocks for larger fees. I'd want some level of comfort that the person handling my half a million dollars knew what they were doing.

Comment: @DStanley Afraid I disagree on all counts.  It's hard to find an advisor who will help you choose broad investments for a small fee. Moreover, financial advisors at this level generally do not possess knowledge that is significantly valuable above what I have described. I've interacted with quite a few and their clients and never seen a case similar to this where the client was better off than doing what I described. My view is that financial advisors are appropriate in cases of mental incapacity or complex legal/financial situations.

Comment: "He feels bad that he missed out on the rally of the past 9 years" ... FOMO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_of_missing_out ... He's too late, but that's ok. Market has been overdue/expected to crash for months now and the world is going to hell. At his age, and given his apparent risk aversion, his best bet is low-risk or buying his dream retirement property to enjoy his golden years w/o having lost his 401(k) to some scam or bubble.

Answer (score 7):

You are asking about how to allocate money. We can't give you an optimal solution to that problem because no one really knows the necessary parameters to solve it. The best you can do are some general guidelines. You can get allocation advice for free by signing up for

http://www.personalcapital.com

or

http://www.futureadvisor.com

Those services won't steer you wrong on the basics.  I suggest them as a starting point.

There are a couple of basic bits of advice to follow, whatever you do.  For example,

- Don't buy municipal bonds unless your father is in a very high tax bracket
- Don't buy any funds with a very high expense ratio (say, above 1%) or with a 12b-1 fee. In fact, try and stay low on the expense ratio.  Consider index funds.
- Diversify across asset classes (domestic and foreign stocks, bonds, primarily).
- It's bad to use a financial advisor in most cases.  They will charge you 1-2% of your father's wealth every year and put you in expensive funds to boot.

One note: Your question suggests that you believe that people should shift away from stocks into bonds as they age.  This is not well-supported by finance theory. There is an optimal mix of risky bonds and stocks that is the same for everyone--though we don't know what it actually is.  What differs between people is how much money to put in risk-free securities (money market and such).  This depends on the person's risk aversion.  Risk aversion may or may not increase as a person ages. Your father's words as stated in the question question suggest that me may not, actually, be very risk averse.

Answer (score 4):

Buying property and renting it out is high risk.  It only takes one tenant who doesn't pay the rent, then wrecks the place before leaving, to wipe out any income you were hoping to receive.

A standard market tracking equity fund is one of the most popular options if you want better returns than cash.  But it isn't risk free.  If the stock market goes down, so does the fund.

Government bonds are lower risk, but lower returns.  Other bonds are as risky as the company or organisation that issues them.

With that amount of money, there's nothing to stop you spreading it across multiple funds.  But multiple funds of the same type isn't really reducing the risk much.

Avoid anything too clever.  If the person offering you an investment can't explain it to you in words *you* understand, turn it down.

If you do go to a financial adviser, read everything they give you, however much that is.  You may find that the product they are selling will generate a lot of money *for them*, while locking you into a long-term investment you don't want.  Don't be afraid to say "no" if it's not what you want.

Comment: I would agree with the rental property and index tracking fund advice. I would disagree with the implied "safety" of government bonds. They are not risk free when inflation and government fiat are present. He stands to lose purchasing power over time with money in bonds. A broad market index fund for all but short term financial needs is "the safest" IMHO. Definitely agree with the statement "avoid anything to clever."

Comment: @rocketman Simon didn't say government bonds are "_risk free_"... he said they "_are lower risk_".

Comment: To add to the tenant thing - we had one who outright refused to leave the property AFTER refusing to pay rent for like a whole year. He was incredibly hard to get the sheriff to issue an eviction since he knew how to silently flee. It took another year for him to mess up badly enough where the swat team raided our house. He came back and stole all the copper out of the walls and flooded the house. $20k in damage. There's a lot more to the story but it's not like we didn't try. Rental property definitely has its risks

Comment: @kai Qing Did you manage the property by yourself? Did you or the property manager check credit history/background search. The motive of this question is to access the risk even if normal precaution is taken.

Comment: @qqqqq - It's family property. I'm not sure what they did for screening back then. I know they run background checks these days. Still, even a good background check can lead to psychotic tenants and extreme cases. They don't happen a lot to us, but we've had a few over the past couple decades. Overall we always came out ahead so it's not like it was a crippling loss when we had to deal with the bad cases.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to tell you what other people *should* be telling you.

If you are asking this question, **you are NOT presently suited to invest your dad's money**. Please tell him to seek out a reputable financial adviser, and/or you can help him put the money into something like Betterment.com where they do the portfolio management for him (you).

Good luck and please do the right thing here. If you love your dad, you really should admit to yourself that you do not currently have the experience or knowledge to do this well.